# Should I specify exact versions in my Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I've noticed that on rubygems.org a lot of the gems suggest you specify them by major version rather than exact version. For example...

[The haml-rails gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/haml-rails)...

```
gem "haml-rails", "~> 0.3.4"  # "$ bundle install" will acquire the 
                              # latest version before 1.0.
```

However, based on the [Bundler docs](https://bundler.io/guides/using_bundler_in_applications.html#adding-gems) it sounded to me like it would be better to nail down the exact version like this...

```
gem "haml-rails", "0.3.4"
```

So there's your haml-rails gem and all its dependencies won't drift forward. If you check out the project on a different machine a few weeks later and run `$ bundle install` you'll have precisely the same versions of everything you specified.

I've seen point releases break stuff, and I thought part of the whole idea of Bundler was to "`Bundle.lock`" all your gem versions.

But on rubygems.org they use "~>" a lot so maybe I'm missing something?

Any clarification would be very helpful to me in understanding Bundler and gem management.

Comment: I would. The less surprises the better. It only takes one time that a dependency updates without you intentionally doing it to send you down a rabbit hole for hours, or days even, to make you learn this lesson. Third-party and open-source libraries cannot be trusted to strictly follow semantic versioning (even my own libraries). Not worth the risk.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

This is the purpose of the Gemfile.lock file - running `bundle install` with a Gemfile.lock present only installs using the dependencies listed in there; it doesn't re-resolve the Gemfile.  To update dependencies / update gem versions, you then have to explicitly do a `bundle update`, which will update your Gemfile.lock file.

If there wasn't a Gemfile.lock, deploying code to production would be a major issue because, as you mention, the dependencies and gem versions could change.

In short, you should be generally safe using the pessimistic version constraint operator (`~>`) as rubygems.org advises.  Just be sure to re-run your tests after you do a `bundle update` to make sure nothing breaks.

There's a [nice article](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/) by Yehuda Katz that has a little more info on Gemfile.lock.

Comment: OK, so gems stay at their established versions recorded in Gemfile.lock. So what's the purpose of adding "~>"? How is that advantageous?

Comment: @ethan RubyGems has a [doc](http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem/Version.html) explaining it (see section "Preventing Version Catastrophe"). The gist of it is it only allows the last integer in the version number to increase (e.g. '~> 1.0.5' allows updating to version 1.0.9999, but never to 1.1.x).  The mechanism is for allowing gems to be updated, but without introducing incompatibilities that may break things (it assumes gems are following the "Rational Versioning" policy that link outlines).

Comment: I think the gist of what you've written is that one should keep pessimistic version constraints in one's *Gemfile* so one *can* easily upgrade to the latest version that matches both the major and minor version specified. But the *Gemfile.lock* file should also be used, and kept in source, so that upgrades must be done explicitly to affect any environment to which your code is deployed.

Answer (score 23):

**TL;DR**

Yes, use [pessimistic locking](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/rubys-pessimistic-operator) (`~>`) and specify a [semantic version](https://semver.org/) down to patch (`Major.minor.patch`) on all your gems!

**Discussion**

I am surprised by the lack of clarity on this issue, even "industry experts" told me the other day that `Gemfile.lock` is there to maintain gem versions. Wrong!

You want to organize your `Gemfile` in such a manner that you can run `bundle update` any time without risking breaking everything. To achive this:

1. Specify a patch-level version for all your gems with pessimistic locking. This will allow `bundle update` to give you fixes, but not breaking changes.
2. Specify a `ref` for gems from git

The only downside to this setup is that when a sweet new minor/major version for a gem comes out, you have to bump the version up manually.

**Warning scenario**

Consider what happens if you do not lock your gems.
You have an unlocked `gem "rails"` in your gemfile and the version in `Gemfile.lock` is `4.1.16`. You are coding along and at some point you do a `bundle update`. Now your Rails version jumps to `5.2.0` (provided some other gem does not prevent this) and everything breaks.
Do yourself a favor and do not allow this for any gem!

**An example Gemfile**

```
# lock that bundler
if (version = Gem::Version.new(Bundler::VERSION)) < Gem::Version.new('1.16.3')
  abort "Bundler version >= 1.16.3 is required. You are running #{version}"
end

source "http://rubygems.org"

# specify explicit ref for git repos
gem "entity_validator",
  git: "https://github.com/plataformatec/devise",
  ref: "acc45c5a44c45b252ccba65fd169a45af73ff369" # "2018-08-02"

# consider hard-lock on gems you do not want to change one bit
gem "rails", "5.1.5"

# pessimistic lock on your common gems
gem "newrelic_rpm", "~> 4.8.0"
gem "puma", "~> 3.12.0"

group :test do
  gem "simplecov", "~> 0.16.1", require: false
end
```

**A concession**
If you are confident your tests will catch bugs introduced by gem version changes, you can try pessimistic-locking gems at minor version, not patch.
This will allow the gem version to increase within the specified major version, but never into the next one.

```
gem "puma", "~> 3.12"
```

Comment: that word pessimistic is confusing here (I understand it's just semantics, but still). if you locked it onto a version with =  , that's pessimistic! but  ~> actually allows you to update to the newest minor version.

Comment: You wrote `You want to organize your Gemfile in such a manner that you can run bundle update any time without risking breaking everything`.   No, this is not the goal.  It sounds like you may not understand the difference between `bundle update` and `bundle install`.  `update` _updates_ the `Gemfile.lock` and changes the versions you're using.  You want to be able to _run `bundle install` any time_ without risking breaking everything.  As it is, you're forcing the `Gemfile` to do what the `Gemfile.lock` is meant to do.

Comment: And those "industry experts" are correct: `Gemfile.lock` *does* in fact maintain gem versions.  Until (of course) you decide to **overwrite it** with `bundle update` (which is basically like saying `bundle overwrite_my_locked_gem_versions`).

Comment: @iconoclast We disagree on the meaning of the word "maintain" then. For me it implies a limited sense of changes to keep with the times, not complete immutability.

Comment: I don't see a difference in our definition of 'maintain'.  `Gemile.lock` maintains (stores) the versions of the gems, but is not completely immutable—it gets mutated when you issue the `bundle update` command.  By _your_ definition the "industry experts" are exactly correct and this answer is misleading everyone who believes it.

Comment: The way I see it (which is the reason I wrote the answer in the first place), there is a misconception that merely because there is a `Gemfile.lock` file that has all the exact versions, developers need not specify gem versions in `Gemfile` (the idea that lock 'maintains' versions). That is false. Developers 'maintain' versions by specifying them in `Gemfile` and running `bundle update` once in a while.

Comment: Personally I prefer my surprises to be small and frequent rather than seldom and earth-shattering. One day there will be a major security fault with a gem and you'll have to upgrade it. At which point you'll descend into upgrade hell as it triggers the need to upgrade other gems, and so on. I recommend writing plenty of system tests + unit test vital components, trim the gemfile of unused gems, and lock down core gems (like rails itself) or that break things if upgraded. Keep up-to-date and fix regularly.

Answer (score 8):

I would definitely say use the exact version numbers. You can probably always just lock it down to a major version, or never specify any version, and be okay, but if you really want that fine grained level of control and to have 100% confidence in your program when being run on other machines, use the exact version numbers.

I've been in situations where the exact version number wasn't specified, and when I or someone else did a `bundle install`, the project broke because it went to a newer version. This can be especially bad when deploying to production.

Bundler *does* lock in your gem specifications, but if you're telling it to just use a major release, then it locks that in. So is just knows "Oh the version is locked in at > 0.1" or whatever, but not "Oh the version is locked in specifically at 0.1.2.3".

Comment: If `Gemfile.lock` is present, then Bundler does, in fact, know which specific version to install (which is why `Gemfile.lock` should be stored in the repo alongside `Gemfile`).

Comment: Doing a `bundle update <gem>` though can end up updating way more than you thought, even if the `Gemfile.lock` is present, and that can be a dangerous and sticky situation.

Comment: I agree with the recommendation from RubyGems themselves on this issue: Just use the pessimistic constraint (~>). This encourages the whole community to pile on semantic versioning, which is a good thing, and between this and the built-in stability features of Gemfile.lock your bases should be more than covered.

Comment: @MrDanA Use the `--source` option for `bundle update`.  So other than that, is there still a reason you see the need for exact versions in `Gemfile`?

Comment: @solidcell I don't believe I should have to put in the source each time I update a gem. I prefer to use as exact a version as I can, but as was mentioned, you can often just use the ~> constraint most of the time. However, I've had that give me a new, bugged version of gems before.

Comment: You do not (and should not) need to use exact versions in your `Gemfile`. This is the purpose of `Gemfile.lock`. If you commit `Gemfile.lock` into source control, someone pulling this and doing `bundle install` will get the exact same versions of gems as you. Setting an exact version in the `Gemfile` stops you from doing `bundle update gem_you_want_to_update` whereas pessimistic versions (`~>`) or no version at all allows you to run `bundle update gem_you_want_to_update` and get the latest (minor) version